# Whether to put special words in headings in italics?

Tags: typography

When we use some term for the first time in a text, it is usually suggested to put in italics. For example:

> Hereinafter, such hyphens are referred to as *connectors*.

My question is whether we should use italics when the first appearance of a term is in a heading. For example:

> ### Embrace the *slug*. (Pro Tip)
>
> Some systems define a *slug* as the part of a URL that identifies a page in human-readable keywords. It is usually the end part of the URL, which can be interpreted as the name of the resource, similar to the basename in a filename or the title of a page. The name is based on the use of the word "slug" in the news media to indicate a short name given to an article for internal use.

Here, I put the word "slug" in italics twice, but I'm not sure it is correct. Maybe I should put it in italics only in the heading? Or only in the normal text ("Some systems define a *slug* as...")?

Comment: There are no specific rules about this. What do you mean "it is usually suggested" ?

Comment: @Lucian By this, I mean the practice that is usually advised in style guides for technical writers and editors. (I'm not a native speaker of English.)

Comment: @johnc.j. Which style guides?  Can't say I've ever seen this before in a heading. TBH it looks a bit odd to me. So I'm just going to say no.

Comment: Ya, I agree with Billy. I would not italicize the term in the header solely because it's new, especially if it's italicized right after like that. If you want to use italics in the title for *emphasis* then that's a different question :)

Comment: @BillyKerr _The IBM Style Guide: Conventions for Writers and Editors._, for example. But they don't say something like "put the first appearance of a new term in italics, **even if this appearance is in a heading**". They just say "put the first appearance of a new term in italics" (it's not a quote). The appearance in headings is not mentioned.

Comment: If it's not mentioned, then I'd avoid it.

Comment: Personal opinion..... there's a reason they are called "guides"" and not "rules". At times guides need to be fluid and waiver, context needs to take precedence.